# ValueError when applying theano's scan function

Tags: python, vectorization, theano, valueerror, theano.scan

I'm trying to evaluate a multivariate normal CDF several times using theano's `scan` function, but I'm getting a ValueError.

Here's an example of the original function I'm trying to vectorize:

```
from scipy.stats.mvn import mvnun # library that calculates MVN CDF

low  = [-1.96, 0   ] # lower bounds of integration
upp  = [0    , 1.96] # upper bounds of integration
mean = [0    , 0   ] # means of the jointly distributed random variables
covs = [[1,0.25],[0.25,1]] # covariance matrix

print(mvnun(low,upp,mean,cov))
```

This produces the following output:

```
(0.19620339269649473, 0)
```

Simple and straightforward, right?

What I'm really trying to do is create 4 large input objects with 1500 elements each. That way, I get to evaluate the `mvnun` function 1500 times. The idea is that at each iteration, all inputs are different from the last, and no information from the previous iteration is necessary.

Here is my setup:

```
import theano
import numpy as np

lower = theano.tensor.dmatrix("lower")      # lower bounds - dim: 1500 x 2
upper = theano.tensor.dmatrix("upper")      # upper bounds - dim: 1500 x 2
means = theano.tensor.dmatrix("means")      # means means -  dim: 1500 x 2
covs  = theano.tensor.dtensor3("covs")      # cov matrices - dim: 1500 x 2 x 2

results, updates = theano.scan(fn=mvnun,
                               sequences=[lower,upper,means,covs])

f = theano.function(inputs=[lower, upper, means, covs],
                    outputs=results,
                    updates=updates)
```

However, when I try to run this block of code, I get an error on the line with the `scan` command. The error states: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`. The full traceback of the error is below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 7, in 
>       sequences=[lower,upper,means,covs])
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\scan_module\scan.py",
>   line 745, in scan
>       condition, outputs, updates = scan_utils.get_updates_and_outputs(fn(*args))
>
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I originally thought that the code wasn't working because the `mvnun` function returns a two-element tuple instead of a single value.

However, when I tried to vectorize a test function (that I created) that also returned a two-element tuple, things worked just fine. Here's the full example:

```
# Some weird crazy function that takes in three Nx1 vectors 
# and an NxN matrix and spits out a tuple of scalars.
def test_func(low_i,upp_i,mean_i,cov_i):
    r1 = low_i.sum() + upp_i.sum()
    r2 = np.dot(mean_i,cov_i).sum()
    test_func_out = (r1,r2)
    return(test_func_out)

lower = theano.tensor.dmatrix("lower")      # lower
upper = theano.tensor.dmatrix("upper")      # upper
means = theano.tensor.dmatrix("means")      # means
covs  = theano.tensor.dtensor3("covs")      # covs

results, updates = theano.scan(fn=test_func,
                               sequences=[lower,upper,means,covs])

f = theano.function(inputs=[lower, upper, means, covs],
                    outputs=results,
                    updates=updates)

np.random.seed(666)

obs = 1500 # number of elements in the dataset
dim = 2 # dimension of multivariate normal distribution

# Generating random values for the lower bounds, upper bounds and means
lower_vals = np.random.rand(obs,dim)
upper_vals = lower_vals + np.random.rand(obs,dim)
means_vals = np.random.rand(obs,dim)

# Creates a symmetric matrix - used for the random covariance matrices
def make_sym_matrix(dim,vals):
    m = np.zeros([dim,dim])
    xs,ys = np.triu_indices(dim,k=1)
    m[xs,ys] = vals[:-dim]
    m[ys,xs] = vals[:-dim]
    m[ np.diag_indices(dim) ] = vals[-dim:]
    return m

# Generating the random covariance matrices
covs_vals = []
for i in range(obs):
    cov_vals = np.random.rand((dim^2 - dim)/2+dim)
    cov_mtx = make_sym_matrix(dim,cov_vals)
    covs_vals.append(cov_mtx)
covs_vals = np.array(covs_vals)

# Evaluating the test function on all 1500 elements
print(f(lower_vals,upper_vals,means_vals,covs_vals))
```

When I run this block of code, everything works out fine and the output I get is a list with 2 arrays, each containing 1500 elements:

```
[array([ 4.24700864,  3.80830129,  2.60806493, ...,  3.12995381, 4.41907055,  4.12880839]), 
 array([ 0.87814314,  1.01768617,  0.45072405, ...,  1.15788282, 0.15766754,  1.32393402])]
```

It's also worth noting that the order in which the vectorized function is getting elements from the sequences is perfect. I ran a sanity check with the first 3 numbers in the list:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(test_func(lower_vals[i],upper_vals[i],means_vals[i],covs_vals[i]))
```

And the results are:

```
(4.2470086396797502, 0.87814313729162796)
(3.808301289302495, 1.017686166097616)
(2.6080649327828564, 0.45072405177076169)
```

These values are practically identical to the first 3 output values in the vectorized approach.

So back to the main problem: why can't I get the `mvnun` function to work when I use it in the `scan` statement? Why am I getting this odd `ValueError`?

Any kind of advice would be really helpful!!!

Thanks!!!